# How to get the Data of PWA Settings Security entities? (Using CSOM or REST API)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, project-server, office-365-groups, pwa

[image]

I want to get the Groups and Users from PWA settings-> Security tab using CSOM or REST API? How do i get it?

Comment: Even I am looking for the same, did you able to find any help?

Comment: Yes I am getting PSI calls to read User and Groups: http://www.umtsoftware.com/blog/how-to-project-online-psi/

And its working for Online PWA.